# Calling component from service - angular

Tags: angular

I already tried a few approaches but none of them seems to work so far.
I am trying to call a function in one component on click event in another component. I don't have any errors in the console.

#### First component

```js
constructor(public projectService: ProjectOverviewService) {  }
delete(event) {
    this.projectService.onFirstComponentButtonClick(); 
}
```

#### Service

```js
invokeFirstComponentFunction = new EventEmitter();
subsVar: Subscription;

onFirstComponentButtonClick() {
    this.invokeFirstComponentFunction.emit();
}
```

#### Second component

```js
constructor(public projectOverviewService: ProjectOverviewService){}
ngOnInit(): void {
if (this.projectOverviewService.subsVar == undefined) {
      this.projectOverviewService.subsVar = this.projectOverviewService.
        invokeFirstComponentFunction.subscribe((name: string) => {
          console.log("I am here!!!");
        });
    }
}
```

I am not hitting `console.log` ever.

Comment: i think it is because you are not catching the emitted event inside the 2nd components html code. can you add your 2 html from 1st and 2nd components? you can check this answer for reference on how to pass events from childen to parents  maybe it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890839/how-can-i-pass-an-array-to-another-component/62891141#62891141

Comment: `ProjectOverviewService` declared as singleton (with `{ providedIn: 'root' }`)?

Comment: @izmaylovdev yes it is
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

Comment: Hey, you should use a Behaviour subject instead of an event emitter.  And pass a value when you emit something. You passed an empty value. If you don't understand what I mean, reply this message and I might show you a demo

Comment: @emmanuelagarry is it different than the 2 answers I got?

Comment: @Fiehra what do you mean? I don't want to pass anything just call the function in on component on click in another but I am missing something and can't figure out what

Comment: @AleksandraMilenković It's almost the same as the second answer. But I will use a behavior subject instead of a subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RXJS import Subject

First component

```
constructor(public projectService: ProjectOverviewService) {  }

delete(event) {
  this.projectService.invokeFirstComponentFunction.next(); 
}
```

Service

```
 public invokeFirstComponentFunction = new Subject();
```

Second Component

```
subsVar: Subscription;


constructor(public projectOverviewService: ProjectOverviewService){}
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subsVar = this.projectOverviewService.invokeFirstComponentFunction.
       .subscribe(() => {
          console.log("I am here!!!");
        });
}
ngOnDestroy(){
this.subsVar && this.subsVar.unsbscribe()
}
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried but it's not working. Breakpoint hits everything except inside subscribe method in the second component

Comment: hmm, ok,  but this is a standard solution to the problem, I think you should check the code well for errors.  good luck ;)

Comment: I wouldn't ask questions here if I could solve it with standard solutions :) our external company also took a look at the code and can't find why it's not working either so thx I will need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to establish communication between 2 components using a service, then event-emitter is not the approach. This is what I would do:

**First component**

```
constructor(public projectService: ProjectOverviewService) {  }
delete(event) {
    this.projectService.onFirstComponentButtonClick("Name"); 
}
```

**Service**

```
invokeFirstComponentFunction = new Subject<string>();
subs$ = this.invokeFirstComponentFunction.asObservable();

onFirstComponentButtonClick(name: string) {
    this.invokeFirstComponentFunction.next(name);
}
```

**Second component**

```
constructor(public projectOverviewService: ProjectOverviewService){}
    
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.projectOverviewService.subs$.subscribe((name: string) => {
    console.log("I am here!!!");
  });
}
```

Comment: I c/p your code but it's still not entering inside the subscribe method

Comment: @AleksandraMilenković do you see any error on the console? Does it enter the onFirstComponentButtonClick method in the service?

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console. Yes it hits onFirstComponentButtonClick method

Comment: Does your SecondComponent implement OnInit? "export class ComponentTwo implements OnInit".This is the only problem I can think of right now. I have created a https://angular-ivy-shlfp2.stackblitz.io project. You can compare your code with mine.